# Content Editor - item selecting action

Tags: content-editor

When I select an item I want to check some fields before it will be displayed in the `Field Editor` and then change values on other fields. So I need to `subscribe` to an event, but such an event doesn't exist out of the box as I can see. So the problem is - if I need to create a custom event, where I need to raise it?

Comment: What are field types you are using?

Comment: Probably better to change the values on save.